# Helm Secrets: Uploading TLS Certs showing blank

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a secrets file that I am wanting to grab two files, a .crt and .key file and make them available in /etc/ssl in my pod. I have everything set up, but when I deploy with Helm, the files are just blank as well as the secrets even though the files exist.

Below is my secrets file:

```
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
    name: "{{ .Values.secret_certs }}"
    labels:
        app: {{ template "connect-mw.name" . }}
        chart: {{ template "connect-mw.chart" . }}
        draft: {{ .Values.draft | default "draft-app" }}
        release: {{ .Release.Name }}
        heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
data:
    connect.crt: |-
  {{ .Files.Get "connect.crt" | b64enc | indent 4 }}
    connect.key: |-
  {{ .Files.Get "connect.key" | b64enc | indent 4 }}
```

And my deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "connect-mw.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "connect-mw.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "connect-mw.chart" . }}
    draft: {{ .Values.draft | default "draft-app" }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 5
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "connect-mw.name" . }}
      release: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "connect-mw.name" . }}
        draft: {{ .Values.draft | default "draft-app" }}
        release: {{ .Release.Name }}
      annotations:
        buildID: {{ .Values.buildID | default "" | quote }}
        container.apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/{{ .Chart.Name }}: runtime/default
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: {{ .Values.securityContext.runAsNonRoot }}
            runAsUser: {{ .Values.securityContext.runAsUser }}
            runAsGroup: {{ .Values.securityContext.runAsGroup }}
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: {{ .Values.securityContext.allowPrivilegeEscalation }}
            seccompProfile:
              type: RuntimeDefault
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: {{ .Values.deployment.containerPort }}
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: {{template "connect-mw.name" .}}
              mountPath: /etc/ssl
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: {{template "connect-mw.name" .}}
          projected:
            sources:
              - secret:
                  name: "{{ .Values.secret_certs }}"
```

The two files are in my path as such when I go to deploy:

```
connect-mw
├── Chart.yaml
├── Chart.yaml.j2
├── connect.crt
├── connect.key
├── templates
│   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   ├── deployment.yaml
│   ├── secrets.yaml
│   └── service.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

Just trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I was able to fix this by loading the files as .txt instead of .crt / .key and leaving the parameters the same. If someone has a solution where I could upload as .crt and .key though that would be cool.